# The expected time until reaching a specified set in a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, stopping-times

I am reading an article in which they discuss a specific Markov chain in an example, and it turns out I need to sharpen up my Markov knowledge.

First the setup.

I have a continuous time Markov chain $(Y(t))_{t\geq 0}$ with discrete state space $S$. I have some subset $B\subset S$, and I have a point $x_0\not\in B$, such that the chain $Y$ starts at $x_0$.

Let $0\leq T_1\leq T_2\leq\cdots$ be the jump times of this Markov chain, and let $T_0=0$. Define the discrete skeleton Markov chain $(X_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ by $X_j=Y(T_j)$, and define then the stopping time $\tau_B$ by
$$\tau_B = \inf\{j>0\ |\ X_j\in B\},$$
so that $\tau_B$ is the first index of $X$ for which $X$ enters the set $B$. Define also the time $\widetilde{\tau}_B$ until we reach the set $B$ as
$$\widetilde{\tau}_B = \sum_{j=0}^{\tau_B-1}(T_{j+1}-T_j) = T_{\tau_B}.$$
Now, let $\Delta_j = \mathbb{E}[T_{j+1}-T_j|X_j]$, so that $\Delta_j$ is the expected time in state $X_j$. Notice that this is a random variable.

My first question is the following. The article notes that $\Delta_j$ is the inverse of the jump rate out of the state $X_j$, but I don't know what this means. Perhaps if $T_{j+1}-T_j|X_j=x$ has an exponential distribution with distribution function $F(t) = 1-\exp{(-\lambda_x)}$, I get something that has mean value equal to $\frac{1}{\lambda_x}$, and if $\lambda_x$ qualifies as the "jump rate", I guess I am done. But what is really the jump rate of a Markov chain, and why (if true) is the difference $T_{j+1}-T_j$ exponentially distributed given $X_j$? Do I need extra assumptions on the chain for this to be true?

Furthermore, the article gives the following expression for the mean value until first reaching $B$:
$$\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{\tau}_B]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\tau_B-1}\Delta_j\right].$$
My second question is, how did this equality occur?
My thoughts so far are:
$$\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{\tau}_B] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\tau_B-1}T_{j+1}-T_j\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\tau_B-1}T_{j+1}-T_j\ |\ X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_{\tau_B}\right]\right].$$

Since $\tau_B$ is determined by the chain up until time $\tau_B$, I can move the sum outside of the inner expectation, so that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\tau_B-1}T_{j+1}-T_j\ |\ X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_{\tau_B}\right]\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\tau_B-1}\mathbb{E}\left[T_{j+1}-T_j\ |\ X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_{\tau_B}\right]\right].$$
Now, if I could remove every step of the chain except for the $j$th one in this last expression, I would be done. Can I do this, and why? I can probably remove the past steps $X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_{j-1}$ (why? this is not precisely the Markov condition), but can I also remove the future steps $X_{j+1},\ldots$?

EDIT: It is example 1 on page 3 of this article: http://www.irisa.fr/armor/Rare/Publis/split.pdf

Best regards.

Comment: I think I get the gist of your question: (i) You are correct, the "jump rate" out of a state $j$ is $v_j = \sum_{k\neq j} q_{jk}$ where $q_{jk}$ are the transition rates.  So $1/v_j$ is the expected time to jump out. (ii) By iterated expectations we get $E[\Delta_j] = E[E[T_{j+1}-T_j|X_j]] = E[T_{j+1}-T_j]$.  So $E[\sum_{j=0}^{\tau_B-1} T_j] = E[\mbox{total time}]$.

Comment: The reason the expected time to jump out is $1/v_j$ is because the min of an independent set of exponential random variables with rates $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ is again exponential with rate $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\ldots +\lambda_n$.

Comment: You prove that by noting $Pr[\min[X_1,\ldots,X_n]>x] =Pr[X_1>x,X_2>x,\ldots,X_n>x]=Pr[X_1>x]Pr[X_2>x]\ldots Pr[X_n>x]$.

Comment: @Michael Sorry but no minimum of exponential times is involved here (and I find your introduction of parameters $\nu_i$ quite misleading).

Comment: @Did  This is standard theory of continuous time Markov chains.  If we are in a state $1$ and there are 2 arrows pointing out, one to state $2$ and another to state $3$, those are labeled with "transition rates" $q_{12}$ and $q_{13}$, meaning that we have two independent racing exponential random variables ($X_{12}$ and $X_{13}$), the first with rate $q_{12}$ the second with rate $q_{13}$, and we transition according to who wins, the winning time is $\min[X_{12}, X_{13}]$, which is again exponential with rate $q_{12}+q_{13}$ and mean $1/(q_{12}+q_{13})$.

Comment: @Did and so for each state $j$ the value $v_j$ is the sum of rates of its outgoing arrows, and $1/v_j$ is the expected time until we transition out (again standard notation).

Comment: @Did this should not be confused with _discrete time Markov chains_ (which this question is not asking about).

Comment: @Michael And you choose lambda_j to denote a transition rate between two states when the OP uses it as the global rate when leaving some state, just to confuse the OP? (And I looove your lessons on elementary theory of Markov chains...)

Comment: Are you familiar with the *semigroup* $P_t$ and *generator* $L$ of a Markov process? At least in the time-homogeneous case, the expected hitting time for a set $A$ can be defined as the solution to $Lf=-1$ off $A$ and $f=0$ on $A$. In the time-homogeneous, discrete state space case, this is just a system of linear equations. The continuous state space case is handled in the same way, except in this case the equation is a linear differential equation. The time-inhomogeneous case requires a different but related approach.

Comment: (Here $f$ is a function of the starting point of the process.)

Comment: @Ian No, I haven't heard of these things. How is $L$ defined? And if $f$ is some function (or vector in the finite state space case?), then what does it have to do with the expected hitting time?

Comment: @HowDoIMath In discrete time, $P_t=P^t$ (where $P$ is the transition matrix) and $L=P-I$. In continuous time, $P_t$ is an operator defined by $(P_t f)(x) = E(f(X_t)|X_0=x)$ and $L$ is an operator defined by $(Lf)(x) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{(P_h f)(x) - f(x)}{h}$. The equations I wrote work in either case. In the case of discrete time, they follow by a simple argument based on conditioning on the value of the chain after one step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, you are correctly interpreting the "jump rate out."

If we are in state 1 and there are two arrows pointing out to states 2 and 3, they are labeled with "transition rates" $q_{12}$ and $q_{13}$.  This means there are two independent racing exponential random variables $Z_{12}$ and $Z_{13}$ with rates $q_{12}$, $q_{13}$, respectively.  We transition according to which one "wins" (meaning which one comes first).  The winning time is $\min[Z_{12},Z_{13}]$, which is again exponentially distributed with rate $q_{12} + q_{13}$ and mean $1/(q_{12} + q_{13})$.

So, if we are in state $j$, we can define $v_j$ as the sum of transition rates out:

$$ v_j = \sum_{k\neq j} q_{jk} $$

and the time to transition out is exponential with rate $v_j$ and mean $1/v_j$ (recall that an exponential random variable with rate $\lambda$ has mean $1/\lambda$).

You can prove that the minimum of independent exponential random variables $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n$ with rates $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n$ is again exponential with rate $\mu_1+\ldots+\mu_n$ by:

\begin{align}
Pr[\min[Z_1,\ldots, Z_n]>z]  &=Pr[Z_1>z,Z_2>z, \ldots, Z_n>z] \\
&= Pr[Z_1>z]Pr[Z_2>z]\ldots Pr[Z_n>z] \\
&= e^{-\mu_1 z} e^{-\mu_2 z} \ldots e^{-\mu_n z} \\
&= e^{-(\mu_1+\ldots+\mu_n)z} 
\end{align}

2) The sum of already-conditioned random variables was more tricky than I first thought and the basic law of iterated expectations I gave in my comments is true but doesn't seem to help.  I like your derivation as is.  You can indeed say:

$$ E[T_{j+1}-T_j|X_0, \ldots, X_{\tau_B}] = E[T_{j+1}-T_j|X_j, \ldots, X_{\tau_B}] $$

by the standard Markov properties.  You can also say:

$$ E[T_{j+1}-T_j|X_j, \ldots, X_{\tau_B}] = E[T_{j+1}-T_j|X_j,X_{j+1}] $$

since future events after we transition to $j+1$ are independent of the transition time from $X_j$ to $X_{j+1}$.  To remove the $X_{j+1}$ conditioning, you need another fact of continuous time Markov chains that the transition time is in fact independent of the state that we visit next (the "winning time" is independent of the state that wins).

---

I could not easily find online links anywhere, so here is one way to prove that the winning time is independent of who wins: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables with rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively.  Define $T=\min[X,Y]$.  Recall that $T$ is exponential with rate $\lambda + \mu$.

Claim: For all $t>0$:

$$ Pr[X<Y|T=t] =  Pr[X<Y] = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+ \mu} $$

Proof:  Fix $\delta>0$.  Then for small $\delta$:

\begin{align} 
Pr[X<Y|T=t] &\approx Pr[X<Y | T \in [t, t+\delta]] \\
&= \frac{Pr[X<Y, T \in [t, t+\delta]]}{Pr[T \in [t, t+\delta]]} \\
& = \frac{Pr[X<Y, X \in [t, t+\delta]]}{Pr[T \in [t, t+\delta]]} \\
&= \frac{\int_{x=t}^{t+\delta} f_X(x)e^{-\mu x}dx}{\int_{x=t}^{t+\delta} f_T(x)dx}  
\end{align}

Taking a limit as $\delta \rightarrow 0$ and using L'Hopital's rule for $0/0$ gives:

\begin{align}  
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}   \frac{\int_{x=t}^{t+\delta} f_X(x)e^{-\mu x}dx}{\int_{x=t}^{t+\delta} f_T(x)dx} &= \lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}  \frac{f_X(t+\delta)e^{-\mu(t+\delta)}}{f_T(t+\delta)}  \\
&=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0} \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda (t+\delta)}e^{-\mu(t+\delta)}}{(\lambda + \mu)e^{-(\lambda + \mu)(t+\delta)}}\\
&=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu} 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I have some follow-up questions. a) First, why is it that the variables $Z_{12}$ and $Z_{13}$ are exponentially distributed in the first place? b) The article claims that $\Delta_j$ is the inverse of the jump rate, but $\Delta_j$ is random, while the jump rates are (as far as I can tell) deterministic. c) You mention that future states $X_k$ for $k>j+1$ are independent of the transition time from state $X_j$ to state $X_{j+1}$. I don't know, can I find a proof of this somewhere? @Michael

Comment: d) And finally, you mention that the transition time $T_{j+1}-T_j$ is independent of the state $X_{j+1}$. I have a difficult time understanding this. What if $X_j=x_1$ and there are only two possible next states $x_2$ and $x_3$, where the jump from $x_1$ to $x_2$ has a huge intensity and the jump from $x_1$ to $x_3$ has a very small intensity. Then $T_{j+1}-T_j$ given $X_j=x_1$ and $X_{j+1}=x_2$ has a very narrow distribution with small mean value, while $T_{j+1}-T_j$ given $X_j=x_1$ and $X_{j+1}=x_3$ has a much longer tail? @Michael

Comment: Appendix 3A.4 here has a brief overview of continuous time Markov chains: http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Queueing_Data_Nets.pdf

Comment: In that link, they use the same $v_i$ notation I gave, and they in fact define the CTMC to transition exponentially with rate $v_i$ and then visit a neighboring state $j$ with prob $q_{ij}/v_i$. It turns out that this is stochastically equivalent to the "independent racing exponential" description I gave above, in which case we _define_ the $Z_{ij}$ random variables as being exponential.

Comment: b) You are right, the $\Delta_j$ as defined is random and depends on $X_j$.  If $X_j=s$, we have $\Delta_j=1/v_s$. I think this is all that paper was trying to say (it could have been more clear on this point).

Comment: c/d)  You are right this is not obvious.  I am looking for a link with the standard proof.  I notice that Exercise 3.12 in the Bertsekas link I gave has a partial statement of what you are asking.  That exercise discusses the fact $Pr[Z_{12}<Z_{13}]=q_{12}/(q_{12}+q_{13})$.  But in fact you can further prove that $Pr[Z_{12}<Z_{13}|\min[Z_{12},Z_{13}]]=q_{12}/(q_{12}+q_{13})$, which means that the winning time is independent of who wins.

Comment: I added to my answer above to give a proof that for all $t>0$ we have $Pr[Z_{12}<Z_{13}|\min[Z_{12},Z_{12}]=t]=q_{12}/(q_{12}+q_{13})$, which means the winning time is independent of who wins.

Comment: This is very useful to me, thank you @Michael I will have a detailed look at your post later today.

Comment: I believe I understand your argument, except I don't really understand if we are looking at the correct probability. To show that the winning time is independent of who wins, I would probably consider $P(T\leq t\ |\ X < Y)$ instead of $P(X<Y\ |\ T=t)$, as the former makes more sense to me as "the distribution of the winning time given that $X$ wins". Maybe I can just flip it around with your expression and Bayes, and maybe a limiting argument. The other conditional probability seems like "the probability that $X$ is winning, given that winning happens at time $t$".

Comment: If you want to flip you get conditional density: $f_{T|X<Y}(t|X<Y) = \frac{Pr[X<Y|T=t]f_T(t)}{Pr[X<Y]} = f_T(t)$, since we already proved that $Pr[X<Y|T=t]=Pr[X<Y] = \lambda/(\lambda + \mu)$. So the conditional PDF for the winning time, given $X$ wins, is the same as the unconditional PDF $f_T(t)$.

Comment: The reason is that in any interval of length $\delta$ that starts before either $X$ or $Y$ has expired, the probability $X$ finishes is $\approx \lambda \delta$, the probability  $Y$ finishes is $\approx \mu \delta$, and the probab they both finish is $O(\delta^2)$ (negligible for small $\delta$).  Regardless of how long they have already waited, the conditional prob of $X$ winning in that interval, given someone wins in that interval, is $\approx \frac{Pr[\mbox{$X$ finishes}]}{Pr[\mbox{$X$ or $Y$ finishes}]} \approx \frac{\delta \lambda}{\delta(\lambda + \mu)} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$.